# What did I Miss in importing css file

Tags: html, css

```
<link rel="styleshet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

It just does Not work, Andy help?

Comment: your rel name is wrong

Comment: rel="stylesheet" is the correct way. You have a typo there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote styleshet instead of stylesheet.. google it next time

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

It's "stylesheet"!